# Amending/deleting Notes or Calendar entries on iPad or in iCloud

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization

I am unfamiliar with iCloud and generally a bit dim. If I amend or delete a note or Calendar entry on my iPad will that change affect the note or Calendar entry in iCloud, and vice versa?

If so, is there a way to delete/amend notes on the iPad but preserving the original in the iCloud?

Comment: "generally a bit dim"...ha!  Thanks for the laugh!

Answer (score 1):

If you are signed into iCloud on your iPad, generally changes you make to iCloud-synced items will sync to your other devices through iCloud.

Particularly for Notes, you can have device-specific notes by doing the following on your iPad:

Go to Settings > Notes and go to the bottom where you should see an "On My iPad" Account option. Toggle that on and you will then have a place in Notes to store notes that stay just on your iPad. This will appear in the list of folders under "ON MY IPAD" and you can create new folders under that section, just as you would for iCloud.

For Calendars, there is no way to maintain a local-only calendar and still sync another calendar to iCloud. (You can do this if you use something *other* than iCloud to sync your calendar, such as Gmail, but not with iCloud.)

Comment: Thank you. I see. Or at least I think I do. So, if I have notes synced to iCloud and later decide that some of those Notes, say for security reasons, should be in iCloud only, I just have to delete them on the device under 'On my iPad.'

Comment: Not exactly. Notes synced to iCloud are separate from "On My iPad". You can remove notes from On My iPad to permanently delete them, but if you remove them from the iCloud folders while using your iPad, they will be deleted from both your iPad and iCloud. You cannot have some notes in iCloud that are only in iCloud and not also visible on your iPad.

Comment: Oh! So you cannot use iCloud to store info. without it also being visible on your iPad. I was hoping to store my passwords there. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I would not suggest using plaintext documents like that for passwords for any number of reasons, not the least of which is security. I would suggest you use something like [1password](https://1password.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your wise counsel Tubedogg. Much appreciated.